# Cannot access my port from other systems in same network

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

My machine is running in Red Hat Linux OS.

I have setup a server using apache in port 8060. I am able to access in localhost but not is other systems for the same network. I am able to ping the machine but not able to access the port

I have checked in iptables. No ports are filtered.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

NMAP Output

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8060/tcp filtered unknown
```

Comment: Check with netstat on which IP listen apache: netstat -an|grep 8060

Comment: This is the output `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN `

Comment: Check also if selinux is enabled and temporary disable it

Comment: SE Linux is already disabled `SELinux status:                 disabled`